# wp_user_query with meta_value_num for leaderboard

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, wp-user-query, username

**Context :** I try to make a custom leaderboard with the WP_USERS_QUERY class and the custom code below. I use the gamipress plugin for points system. The leaderboard works fine, displaying correctly the name of the users website and total points they have earned.

However, I have a issue with the $args of my custom users query.

**Issue :** The leaderboard should display in this order : the hightest gamipress point, and the date of the user registered. But, the **username with number (8doz and 2pyr) are at the top of the list** (this's not the desired result). It's seems the 'meta_value_num' of 'orderby' considere the username with number.

My example below. It actually display like this :

```
1st place - 8doz - 0 pt
2nd place - 2pyr - 0 pt
3rd place - frozenk - 2 pts
4th place - Gam3rSkill - 2 pts
5th place - Fr4gments 1 pts
6th place - MacX - 0 pts
etc...
```

But it should display like this :

```
1st place - frozenk - 2 pts
2nd place - Gam3rSkill - 2 pts
3rd place - Fr4gments 1 pts
4th place - MacX - 0 pts
5nd place - 2pyr - 0 pt
6ft place - 8doz - 0 pt
```

Here my code :

```
    'role' => 'Subscriber',
    'orderby' => array('meta_value_num', 'user_registered'),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_gamipress_point_points',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => '_gamipress_point_points',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                ),
    )
);

$subscribers_with_point_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

I put the 'relation' and 'compare' key like this to display users that's they doesn't earned any point.

Any ideas or explanations to display correctly my users by number of points that they earned, however they usernames ?

Thanks a lot !